# square integrable of f(x)

Tags: integration

Suppose f(x) is a square integrable function i.e. integral of square of f(x) is finite. Then what will be the integral of f(x) only from -infinity to +infinity? Pls if possible give an example for the same.

Comment: if you consider measurable functions on a *finite* measurable space, then if the function $f$ is square integrable it's also integrable, namely $L^2\subseteq L^1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral may exist or it mya not.
For example, with $f(x)=\frac1x$ over $[1,\infty)$, we have $\int_1^af(x)\,\mathrm dx=\ln a\to \infty$. In that case we could still say that $\int_1^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx=+\infty$, but it may also be the case that $\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx$ fails to converge as $a\to\infty$ or $b\to -\infty$ (due to oscillation).